# Join a dataframe and a list into a dataframe containing a listcolumn

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'd like to merge a dataframe with an id column and a list based on the name of the list (containing the different id values). As an example:

```
g <- data.frame(id = c("a1", "b2"), k = c(4, 5))
h <- list(a1 = list(
  p = c(1, 2, 3),
  l = c("A", "B", "C"),
  data = mtcars
),
b2 = list(
  p = c(5, 6, 7),
  l = c("M", "N", "O"),
  data = iris
))
```

How can I then merge g and h (based on g$id and the names of h) into a dataframe g2 containing id and k columns in addition to h as a list-column:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
     id                  h       k
  <fctr>              <list> <dbl>
1      a1     <tibble [3*1]>     4
2      b2     <tibble [3*1]>     5
```

---

The answer by @Steven Beaupré  is superuseful. I took the Liberty of converting the list to tibble method into a function in case anyone else needs it.

```
library(tidyverse)
cnv_list_tibble <- function(ls) {
  as_tibble(ls) %>%
    gather(id, data) %>%
    nest(.,-id)
}
```

and voila you have a list-column that can be used for subsequent merging/joining.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

as_tibble(h) %>% 
  gather(id, data) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  do(h = as_tibble(.[-1])) %>%
  left_join(., g)
```

Which gives:

```
#Joining, by = "id"
#Source: local data frame [2 x 3]
#Groups: <by row>
#
## A tibble: 2 × 3
#     id                h     k
#  <chr>           <list> <dbl>
#1    a1 <tibble [3 × 1]>     4
#2    b2 <tibble [3 × 1]>     5
```

---

Or using `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

as_tibble(h) %>%
  gather(id, data) %>%
  slice_rows("id") %>%
  by_slice(~as_tibble(.), .to = "h") %>%
  left_join(., g)
```

Comment: The do-version throws the following error in dplyr 0.5.0: Joining, by = c("id", "h")
Error: Can't join on 'h' x 'h' because of incompatible types (list / list)

Comment: @Misha I'm using `dplyr_0.5.0.9000` and it works fine. I'm confused as to why it says `Joining by = c("id","h")` ... there is no "h" column in `g`.

Comment: I upgraded to 0.5.0.9000 -- now it works. I have no idea as to the "h" column in g. Thx.

Comment: see the edit. Using nest instead of group_by/do is even shorter and more concise.

Comment: @Misha Good one ! Nice improvement !